# Java retuned element type of a nested list

Tags: java

What I would like to achieve is to have a nested list (or array) with elements as lists (or arrays) consisting a pair of integers. This is to store some data and I would like to access those integers efficiently.

So I created a nested list in Java like this:

```
List combined = new ArrayList();
int x[] = new int[2];
List segl = Arrays.asList(x)
combined.addAll(segl);
```

the nested list will later be appended with more list like segl.
Now I want to return a element from combined. But with `combined.get(0)` the returned element data type is object instead of a list like segl, so I couldn't do anything with it (eg. return the single int element from segl. I have no idea how to change it to a list or array.

Comment: You are using [*raw types*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) all over the place. `List` and `ArrayList` expect a [type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) to be given: `List<int[]>`. Oh, and I suggest not to mix arrays and `List`s, unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: As the previous comments points out, you are getting `Objects` because you are using raw types. However, could you expand on what you are trying to achieve? Is `combined` supposed to be a 'List of Lists'? (e.g. `List<List<Integer>`?)

Comment: @ Wouter van der Linde I'm new to Java. Just searched on raw type and trying out with parameterization. What I would like to achieve is to have a nested list (or array) with elements as lists (or arrays) consisting of 2 integers. This is to store some data and I would like to access those integers efficiently.

Comment: At this point you should not get worried about efficiency. If you need a pair of integers for some reason, you should create a class that collects these integers. Maybe a Point for x-y information, or a Location for latitude and longitude. The make a List<Point>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided in the comments, you want to have 'List of Lists' where the second `List` has two elements. Unfortunately you can't use arrays as the generic type of a List. So what I think that you want to do is probably this:

```
// This is a List which holds other Lists.
List<List<Integer>> combined = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer seql = new ArrayList<>(2); // Initialize with a size of 2.
// add justs adds seql to combined. addAll will add all elements of seql to combines
combined.add(segl);
```

This makes it so that `combined.get(0)` returns a `List<Integer>`.

If you are using an array you have two options:

```
   // Using Arrays.asList(..) 
   List<List<Integer>> combined = new ArrayList<>();
   Integer[] seql = new Integer[2];
   combined.add(Arrays.asList(segl));

   //If Integer[] is not possible.
   List<List<Integer>> combined = new ArrayList<>();
   int[] seql = new int[2];
   List<Integer> seqlAsList = Arrays.stream(seql).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
   combined.add(seqlAsList );
```

Comment: Using `arrays`: If you know how many lists (or arrays) you want to add to `combined` you could also try something like this.
`int[][] combined = new int[100][2];`
Where you can then access each `seql` using indices:
First element: `combined[0][0]`
Second element: `combined[0][1]`

Comment: The no. of pairs to be added is unknow. I tired your method it indeed returned List<Integer> for the pair. Let's say I used 'List<Integer> aa = combined.get(0);'. But when I use 'int aaa = aa.get(0);' to get back the single integer it doesn't work. could you point out why?

Comment: Could you be more precise as to what 'doesn't work'? `aa.get(0)` should return an `int`. Did you add an `int` to `aa` before accessing it? (e.g. did you do something like `aa.add(5)`?

Comment: I think I understand, you are trying to access a non-existing element. (There is nothing at `aa.get(0)` so that call returns `null`) Because of `Generics` you can only add the `Integer` wrapper type to the list. If you do things like `int aaa = aa.get(0)` Java will automatically `autobox` that to an `int` (primitive) That doesn't work if `aa.get(0)` is nothing as Java tries to `autobox` a `null`-value. You will need to add elements to `aa` before accessing them. :)

Comment: I think I know where's the issue but I'm not sure how to fix it. Actually the integer pair seql is from somewhere else, so I now have  ```int seg[] = new int[2];         seg[0]=5;         seg[1]=4;      List ss = Arrays.asList(seg);     List<Integer> segl =  ss;   ``` that's how segl is currently defined. Also as you can see aa is not empty. The error message is 'class [I cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer ([I and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')'.

Comment: Ah, my bad. You can't use `Arrays.asList(..)` when using an `int[]`. That only works with `Integer[] aa = new Integer[2]; I`ll update the answer with a solution for both `Integer[]`  and `int[]`.

Comment: It finally worked. Thank you so much for the help. I've been stuck at this issue for the whole day...

Comment: Awesome! And no problem. :) Glad to read it works!